# Failed conversion from String to Byte in the entity generated by Jhipster

Tags: java, mongodb, blob, jhipster

When I generate an entity that has an attribute with type `blob`, using Jhipster , I got this error log when displaying the entity:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [byte] for value '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'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEMAAABECAYAAADaz4jLAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAALiIAAC4iAari3ZIAABo8SURBVHhe7ZsHdJRV+sYHCSRB8b+Ci+4CARJIJpOEJIQAUpQWVEAXEOkgXYEjPoiuadUb0uHRYRoszWGfQHfIFUuQwG0q84eBK4kCp3laGDJdSuiOoZQZfQUM270w2bZrloKS/x5LWe/klA4hpIXe14+gI2JGnur3PkWu49W8KBCMmeTsaM0wazKQzJhAGt/AxY+kM5gwLYZiH5cDCDdvTfR2EIL/vdOIpAnmEq4r8E8zLQ0/zVdzI4QVkE8Z9EV9b3iN=="
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:203)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToArrayConverter.convert(StringToArrayConverter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:203)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1224)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1170)
```

Help please

Comment: Put yout code here. So it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Did you modify the generated code ? If it's not the case, please open an issue on the [bug tracker](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues) and give all the info asked in the guidelines.